# Upload multiple large files to s3 using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5, amazon-s3

Anyone knows how to upload large multiple files to s3 with laravel 5?
i tried to use streams but it works only for files less than 5M, here is my code:

```
foreach ($request->file('photos') as $file) {  
  $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
  $filePath = '/uploads/' . $filename;
  $stream = fopen($file->getRealPath(), 'r+');
  $s3->put($filePath, $stream);
}
```

i tried to update settings in my php.ini as well like this but no change

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

Comment: try to inject some cgi uploader script for large files. because cgi upload files in chunks and will not break your system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who are facing a similar problem,
i added this to my controller and it worked for me

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing post_max_size in php.ini to

```
post_max_size = 50M;
```